# To BIN or not to BIN a continuous data to get a Fragment Size Distribution?

Tags: distributions, excel, continuous-data, frequency, binning

I have a data set in excel of almost 6000 entries (quantitative and continuous => P(X=x)=0, I mean the possible values for my continuous random variable X are uncountably many). Each point will represent a particle with a determined surface area.

```
     A total of 5168 enclaves with a large 
     variability of size (area) ranging
     from 2.00x10^-3 to 7,98x10^2 mm2.
     With an increment=0,0002 , calculated in excel by =1/COUNT(A:A) (A=column with the values of surface area).
```

I need to determine the ***Fragment Size Distribution*** (FSD), and present it as ***Cumulative Frequencies***, on log-log plots, **where the slope of the linear point arrangement is the value I need to get (Fractal Dimension of the FSD).**

Since I'm a beginner in statistics, and I have read that it's not necessary (nor recommended?) to bin continuous data, I wonder if there any good way to do this, without binning my data? 
I have tried the following:

- I tried calculating the Cumulative frequencies by binning (in an empirical way), with different bin width and the value of my slope changed with every new value.
- I applied Freedman-Diaconis Rule trying to “bin” my data:
  [image]
  Applying log scale for the y-axis:
  [image]
  Freedman-Diaconis Rule: Gives high number of bins, distribution positively skewed, but the distribution does not show much information, since many of the latest classes have no population.
- I plotted the Cumulative Normal Distribution (on excel), as well as the CDF (Cumulative DIstribution Function), then I applied log-log, but I didn't get a linear point arrangement.
  [image]
  [image]

Is there a problem with my data? I tried it again using just part of the data, but it didn't work either.
If I don't bin my data what is the correct way to proceed with my data set to determine the ***Fragment Size Distribution*** (FSD), as ***Cumulative Frequencies***?

Probably this hasn't much sense since my statistical knowledge is very basic, but I really hope you could understand and could help me out here.